# Gulp-sass выдает ошибку, когда применяются изменения в @import-файлах

Tags: javascript, gulp, sass, scss

Использую gulp-sass для компиляции scss файлов. В одном каталоге находится главный файл **style.scss** и файл, который импортируется в главный **print.scss**. **main.scss** нормально компилируется без ошибок и принимает значения в файле **print.scss**, но как только я хочу сохранить изменения в файле **print.scss**, выдает ошибку:

```
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
 Error: app\scss\style.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: _print
       Parent style sheet: stdin
        on line 3 of stdin
>> @import "_print";
   ^

    at options.error (E:\ready\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:277:32)
```

Ниже привожу файл **gilfile.js** и остальные файлы которые могут помочь для решения данной проблемы.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sassGlob = require('gulp-sass-glob');
// var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var cssGlobbing = require('gulp-css-globbing');


var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

var useref = require('gulp-useref');

var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var gulpIf = require('gulp-if');

var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');

var del = require('del');

var runSequence = require('run-sequence');


gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app'
    }
  })
})


gulp.task('sass', function(){
 return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
// .pipe(cssGlobbing({
//       extensions: ['.scss']
//     }))
.pipe(sassGlob())
    .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(autoprefixer({
    browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
    cascade: false
  }))
  .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))

  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({
    stream: true
  }))

  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
})

gulp.task('useref', function(){
  return gulp.src('app/*.html')
  .pipe(useref())
    // Minifies only if it's a JavaScript file
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
  })


gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return del.sync('dist').then(function(cb) {
    return cache.clearAll(cb);
  });
})

gulp.task('clean:dist', function() {
  return del.sync(['dist/**/*', '!dist/images', '!dist/images/**/*']);
});

gulp.task('fonts', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))
})


// Watchers
gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function(){
  gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']); 
  gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
  // Other watchers
})

gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
  runSequence(['sass', 'browserSync', 'watch'],
    callback
    )
})

gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  runSequence(
    'clean:dist',
    // ['sass', 'useref', 'images', 'fonts'],
    ['sass', 'useref', 'fonts'],
    callback
    )
})
```

Общий **html-код** элемента:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--build:css css/style.min.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Добро пожаловать!</h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        <h2>Секция документа</h2>
        <p>Проверяем компиляцию файлов</p>
        <p>Не обьеденяет в один css несколько фалов</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h1>Всего две команды:</h1>
        <p>gulp build</p>
        <p>gulp default</p>
    </section>

    <section class="flex">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </section>

    <section class="print">
        <h2>ЭТО, ПРИНТ</h2>
        <a href="#">
            <div>
                <p>Раздумье</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </section>

<!--build:js js/main.min.js -->
    <script src="js/carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/gallery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/nav.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

Код элемента где вложенность **.scss** (**style.scss**) работает:

```
@import "_print";
@import "_mixins";


.testing {
    width: pecentage(5/7);
}

body {
    background: grey;
    h1 {
        color:white;
        @include font-size(40px);
        background: green;
    }
}

section {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    div {
        width: 30%;
        background: orange;

        &:hover {
            background: red;
        }
    }
}
```

Как это исправить и что здесь не так ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашел такой выход из данной ситуации:

**1)** Устанавливаем **gulp-sass-glob**;
**2)** В задачах ставим его **перед отслеживанием sass**;
**3)** Устанавливаем вывод ошибки но не прекращение процесса отслеживания;
**4)** В случае ошибки несколько раз сохраняем файл, пока система не применит    изменения или просто разово сохраняем главный файл, куда импортируем дочерние;
**5)** Все миксины и переменные придется импортировать в каждый файл, потому как в друго случае работать они не могут.

**P.S** это один из вариантов решения, ничего по делу не нашел, если кто-то знает   более еффективный путь решения, буду рад увидеть и применить! Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Есть как минимум 3 варианта исправления проблемы:
**1.** Предполагает хорошее понимание `Node.js`, а так же работу `node-sass` и `libsas`, которые собственно и выполняют компиляцию файлов.
Его суть заключается в написании собственного обработчика подключаемых файлов. Если заглянуть в [документацию](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass#importer--v200---experimental) к `node-sass`, то можно увидеть в объекте `options` ключ `importer`, который на самом деле является пользовательской функцией. Когда `LibSass` встречает директиву `@import`. Пользовательский импортер позволяет расширить движок `LibSass` как в синхронном, так и асинхронном режиме.
**2.** Этот способ основан на небольшом хаке в `watch` задаче и сводиться к добавлению таймера на выполнение `sass` задачи:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    watch('dev/scss/**/*.scss', function(event, cb) {
        setTimeout(function(){gulp.start('sass');},500) // задача выполниться через 500 миллисекунд и файл успеет сохраниться на диске
    });
});
```

Здесь я использовал плагин `gulp-watch`, но думаю и со стандартным галповским вотчером это прокатит.
**3.** Использование именно плагина `gulp-watch`, он принимает вторым параметром объект с опциями, среди которых есть задержка равная по умолчанию 10 миллисекундам.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
        watch('dev/scss/**/*.scss', {readDelay: 100}, function(event, cb) {
            gulp.start('sass');
        });
    });
```

Подробнее можно почитать в [документации](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch#optionsreaddelay)

Answer (score 0):

```
@import "_print"; @import "_mixins";
```

в style.scss надо сделать:

```
@import "print"; @import "mixins";
```

т.е. без нижних подчеркиваний. Из-за них и ошибка была.

Answer (score 0):

В случае если gulp-sass не сработает при таком записи: npm i gulp-sass --save-dev, то нужно запустит сначала: npm i gulp-sass -g, а потом  npm i gulp-sass --save-dev

Comment: Зачем Вы публикуете копию своего же малополезного ответа второй [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1121878/365775)? Да еще и оба ответа на несколько лет как закрытых вопросах!