# С чем связана ошибка при компиляции sass через gulp?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, sass

Структура проекта такая на данный момент такая:

[image: Структура проекта]

Внутри app.scss идет подключение следующих файлов:

```
@import 'partials/base';
@import 'partials/navbar';
```

Я использую gulp для сборки проекта.
gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

var path = {
  src: {
    styles: './assets/scss/app.scss',
    jade: './assets/**/*.jade'
  },
  public: {
    styles: './public/css',
    jade: './public/',
  },
  watch: {
    styles: './assets/**/*.scss',
    jade: './assets/**/*.jade',
  }
};

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src(path.src.styles)
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(autoprefixer({
    browsers: ['last 5 version']
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(path.public.styles))
});

gulp.task('jade', function() {
  return gulp.src(path.src.jade)
  .pipe(jade({
    pretty: true
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(path.public.jade))
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(path.watch.styles, ['styles']);
  gulp.watch(path.watch.jade, ['jade']);
});
```

Возникает проблема: Я отслеживаю изменения во всех .scss-файлах. И если я компилирую app.scss, то все отрабатывает нормально. Если я изменяю один из двух подключаемых файлов, то с первого раза все работает хорошо, а во второй раз получается следующая ошибка:

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: assets\scss\app.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ./partials/base
   Parent style sheet:D         D:/Developement/OpenServer/domains/revival.layout/assets/scss/app.scss
    on line 3 of assets/scss/app.scss
>> @import './partials/base';
   ^
```

Почему она может возникать и как с ней справиться?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Gulp-sass выдает ошибку, когда применяются изменения в @import-файлах](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501570/gulp-sass-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-import-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тексту ошибки gulp не может найти `'./partials/base';`, попробуйте задать путь для scss более широко, вероятно этот файл не попадает в билд

```
var path = {
    src: {
        styles: './assets/**/*.scss',
        jade: './assets/**/*.jade'
      },
```