# Ошибка при компиляции *.sass через Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, sass, gulp-sass

Для проекта нужно сделать компиляцию `*.sass`  файлов через `gulp`. Я установил `gulp` и `gulp-sass`  модули через npm(`sudo npm i --save-dev gulp && sudo npm i --save-dev gulp-sass`). Создал и заполнил файл `gulpfile.js`(Содержание ниже). Пытаюсь запустить(`gulp sass:watch`) и ошибка.

Содержимое `gulpfile.js`

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./sass/**/*.sass')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']);
});
```

Содержимое ошибки

```
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/surokdima/Programming/JavaScript/GenerateCssApp/gulpfile.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

Также пытался убрать `'use strict';`. Но ошибка осталась.

Потом попытался запустить вот так `gulp sass:watch --use-stric`t.

Тогда получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/surokdima/Programming/JavaScript/GenerateCssApp/node_modules/globule/node_modules/glob/glob.js:39:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

В чём ошибки понять не могу. Помогите пожалуйста устранить эту проблему. Буду благодарен любому ответу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется, что ошибка находится внутри кода gulp-sass. Какая версия у вас node.js?  При старых версиях, нельзя употреблять "let".  Возможно, gulp-sass употребляет "let".

Comment: Большое спасибо. Обновил ноду и заработало.

Answer (score 0):

В случае если gulp-sass не сработает при таком записи: npm i gulp-sass --save-dev то нужно запустит сначала: npm i gulp-sass -g а потом  npm i gulp-sass --save-dev