# Gulp, периодически ошибка в sass

Tags: gulp, sass, scss

http://joxi.ru/n2Y8YyziodELBm

Ошибка выскакивает именно при сохранении import файлов. При чем она возникает примерно на 1 ctrl+s из 5 . В итоге приходится периодически по несколько раз сохранять, не совсем удобно.

Кто знает в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Возможный дубликат вопроса. Предлагаю вам ознакомится с данным вопросом `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501570/gulp-sass-выдает-ошибку-когда-применяются-изменения-в-import-файлах`. Без ваших *task* невозможно определить в чем ошибка, но в данном вопросе все варианты подробно расписаны.

Answer (score 0):

посмотрите сюда, мне помогло задержка на watch (вторым параметром) вот здесь человек описал [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/631933/282812][1]

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
     watch('dev/scss/**/*.scss', {readDelay: 100}, function(event, cb) {
         gulp.start('sass');
     });
 });
```