# Проблема с @import в sass

Tags: gulp, sass, импорт

При компиляции sass файла происходит ошибка с импортом.

[image: ошибка]

Вот содержимое файла  main

[image: main]

и импортируемого _header

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Читал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501570/gulp-sass-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-import-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85) и [тут](https://geekbrains.ru/topics/4293) про задержку, но так и не смог разобраться

Вот содержимое галпфайла, его брал [здесь](https://webdesign-master.ru/blog/tools/2016-03-09-gulp-beginners.html)

```css
var gulp       = require('gulp'), // Подключаем Gulp
 sass         = require('gulp-sass'), //Подключаем Sass пакет,
 browserSync  = require('browser-sync'), // Подключаем Browser Sync
 concat       = require('gulp-concat'), // Подключаем gulp-concat (для конкатенации файлов)
 uglify       = require('gulp-uglifyjs'), // Подключаем gulp-uglifyjs (для сжатия JS)
 cssnano      = require('gulp-cssnano'), // Подключаем пакет для минификации CSS
 rename       = require('gulp-rename'), // Подключаем библиотеку для переименования файлов
 del          = require('del'), // Подключаем библиотеку для удаления файлов и папок
 imagemin     = require('gulp-imagemin'), // Подключаем библиотеку для работы с изображениями
 pngquant     = require('imagemin-pngquant'), // Подключаем библиотеку для работы с png
 cache        = require('gulp-cache'), // Подключаем библиотеку кеширования
 autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');// Подключаем библиотеку для автоматического добавления префиксов

gulp.task('sass', function(){ // Создаем таск Sass
 return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass') // Берем источник
  .pipe(sass()) // Преобразуем Sass в CSS посредством gulp-sass
  .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { cascade: true })) // Создаем префиксы
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) // Выгружаем результата в папку app/css
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})) // Обновляем CSS на странице при изменении
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() { // Создаем таск browser-sync
 browserSync({ // Выполняем browserSync
  server: { // Определяем параметры сервера
   baseDir: 'app' // Директория для сервера - app
  },
  notify: false // Отключаем уведомления
 });
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
 return gulp.src([ // Берем все необходимые библиотеки
  'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', // Берем jQuery
  'app/libs/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' // Берем Magnific Popup
  ])
  .pipe(concat('libs.min.js')) // Собираем их в кучу в новом файле libs.min.js
  .pipe(uglify()) // Сжимаем JS файл
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js')); // Выгружаем в папку app/js
});

gulp.task('css-libs', ['sass'], function() {
 return gulp.src('app/css/libs.css') // Выбираем файл для минификации
  .pipe(cssnano()) // Сжимаем
  .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'})) // Добавляем суффикс .min
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')); // Выгружаем в папку app/css
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'css-libs', 'scripts'], function() {
 gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']); // Наблюдение за sass файлами в папке sass
 gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload); // Наблюдение за HTML файлами в корне проекта
 gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);   // Наблюдение за JS файлами в папке js
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
 return del.sync('dist'); // Удаляем папку dist перед сборкой
});

gulp.task('img', function() {
 return gulp.src('app/img/**/*') // Берем все изображения из app
  .pipe(cache(imagemin({ // С кешированием
  // .pipe(imagemin({ // Сжимаем изображения без кеширования
   interlaced: true,
   progressive: true,
   svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
   use: [pngquant()]
  }))/**/)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img')); // Выгружаем на продакшен
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'img', 'sass', 'scripts'], function() {

 var buildCss = gulp.src([ // Переносим библиотеки в продакшен
  'app/css/main.css',
  'app/css/libs.min.css'
  ])
 .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))

 var buildFonts = gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*') // Переносим шрифты в продакшен
 .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))

 var buildJs = gulp.src('app/js/**/*') // Переносим скрипты в продакшен
 .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))

 var buildHtml = gulp.src('app/*.html') // Переносим HTML в продакшен
 .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

});

gulp.task('clear', function (callback) {
 return cache.clearAll();
})

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Структура

[image: каталог]

Прошу помощи в решении этой проблемы

Comment: main и _header лежат в одном каталоге?

Comment: Да, все sass файлы в одном каталоге